# How to display output when the Inner Select Query returns multiple values?

Tags: sql, select

The inner Select returns multiple values which I am not able to display and getting error. The first select has multiple columns wherein one of the column values are fetched through an inner query which returns multiple values. I want all the inner select values.

```
 select t.SiteId, t.Name, t.IsHoliday, t.DateStart, t.DateEnd, t.Year,
    (
    select count(te.Name), te.Name
    from Term te
    inner join Site_Program_Term spt on te.Id = spt.TermId
    where te.Year = 2015 and te.SiteId = 2
    group by te.Name
    ) from Term t where t.SiteId=2 and t.year=2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery, not aggregation.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.SiteId, t.Name, t.IsHoliday, t.DateStart, t.DateEnd, t.Year,
       (select count(*)
        from Site_Program_Term spt 
        where t.Id = spt.TermId
       )
from Term t
where t.SiteId = 2 and t.year = 2015;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are using the subquery you need to write it in a way only one record is selected. You can't have multiple results.

My suggestions is to run the subquery alone and check the results.

Based on that you should figure out which of all the records is the one you actually want, and see what condition your are missing for only that record to be selected.

The other alternative is that you are not thinking the query in the correct way.

More than one result in this kind of subqueries would be like trying to sit two people in the same seat at the same time.